# Separate text with a number as separator

Tags: php

I have text like `"My Cart n items"` (e.g. `"My Cart 2 items"`).

I want to separate it into two PHP variables, such that the first is like `"My Cart"` and the second like `"2 items"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: NB: the first part can be composed of only one word: in german : "Warenkorb 2 Artikel"; Thanks

Comment: `It's always ine the form "My Cart n itmes"` or can it, in fact, be in a different language altogether? Be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(.*?)(\d.*)/', $text, $parts);
print_r($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [strpbrk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) function. For example, calling

```
echo strpbrk("My Cart 2 items", "0123456789")
//Echoes "2 items"
```

Answer (score -1):

A regular expression that splits a string by the spaces before numerical characters should do the trick

```
$result = preg_split("/ (?=\d)/g", $myoldtext);
```

This would result in an array containing your two strings

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but there is no `g` modifier in the split regex.